# Sound designing for an Iphone Game - approaches? 

Tags: iphone, mobile-phone, sound-design

Hello everyone, this is my first time posting. I really love this site, it's a brilliant idea!

My question is this, 
I may have just landed a gig sound designing about 10 sounds for an iphone game that's currently in development.

I'm curious about the frequency response of the iphone speakers and headphone out, as well as any info related to sound optimization for the iphone, i.e. Mix levels, amount of compression needed etc.

Additionally are there any big no no's that should be avoided when creating sounds for the iphone? 
Do any of you have experience sound designing for phone apps/games?

Thanks for your time, interests and energy! 
I love this site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some other things that are probably worth bearing in mind:

http://www.gamesounddesign.com/tips-and-tricks-for-iphone-sound-design.html

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! Thank you Joe. 

Comment: Glad to see my time spent trawling the internet hasn't been in vain :)

Answer (score 1):

Grab a set of the white stock Apple headphones and cross-reference your mix on those because that's what 90% of the people will be listening to the game with.

I heard they roll off at 16K. I could be wrong, though.

I mix a weekly podcast and I always reference my mix on those because that's what people end up listening to it on mostly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ryan. 
I've got a set of those laying around, so I'll be sure to do that. 

just checked the specs of the audio out on the iphone and it says it goes from 20-20khz... but I do wonder how flat that response is. 

Comment: lol. @zenandtheart I'm sure they go from 20 to 20, but the curve must be like \

Answer (score 1):

Also, you won't have any bass to speak of when they're not wearing the headphones, so try to keep that in mind.